# Replacing a leading text string with the same string in python

Tags: python, xml

I have the following tags in a xml file as

> &\hbox{(1b)}}$$ with the initial
>   condition <2inline-formula>$x(0)$, where the subscript
>   <3inline-formula>$p$ means
>   'plant’; <4inline-formula>$x_{p}(t) \in \Re^{n}$ is
>   the state, <5inline-formula>$y_{p}(t)\in\Re^{q}$ is the
>   output, and <6inline-formula>$u_{p}(t)\in\Re^{m}$ is the
>   input; <7inline-formula>

I want to replace the inline-formulas which are all starting with numbers to `<inline-formula>` but i am not able to give the condition to search for the inline formula staring with numbers so any help on this.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use regular expresions (`re` module) for detecting one or more digits preceeding "inline-formula" (`\d+inline-formula`).

Like this for example:

```
>>> import re
>>> original = "&\hbox{(1b)}}$$ with the initial condition <2inline-formula>$x(0)$, where the subscript <3inline-formula>$p$ means 'plant’; <4inline-formula>$x_{p}(t) \in \Re^{n}$ is the state, <5inline-formula>$y_{p}(t)\in\Re^{q}$ is the output, and <6inline-formula>$u_{p}(t)\in\Re^{m}$ is the input; <7inline-formula>"
>>> new = re.sub(r"<\d+inline-formula>", "<inline-formula>", original)
>>> print new
"&\\hbox{(1b)}}$$ with the initial condition <inline-formula>$x(0)$, where the subscript <inline-formula>$p$ means 'plant\xe2\x80\x99; <inline-formula>$x_{p}(t) \\in \\Re^{n}$ is the state, <inline-formula>$y_{p}(t)\\in\\Re^{q}$ is the output, and <inline-formula>$u_{p}(t)\\in\\Re^{m}$ is the input; <inline-formula>"
>>>
```

Comment: If i want to add multiple conditions in the same re.sub method is it possible to do so. like i want to do one more replacement for tag <1disp-formula> to <disp-formula>